# subprocess.Popen and communicate() don't execute the program, while Terminal does

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess, popen, execution

I have a routine that I run every morning, where I want a sequence of programs to run. It looks something like this. (content of programCaller.py)

```
programs = [
    'program 1',
    'program 2',
    'program 3'
    ]

for program in programs:
    print('Executing: ' + program)
    p = subprocess.Popen('/path/to/directory/' + program)
    p.communicate()
```

Everything was working great until a week or so ago. It communicated in real time (perk that I struggled to obtain on Windows, as I am running this on Mac), and if a program fails, it goes to the next one.

Now it won't just run from IDLE. However, it works just fine from the Terminal "./programCaller.py".

All the programs have shebang lines and permission of course. I have tried all variations of shell=True, executable, stdout and the other arguments, but it won't work.

What it does is that it instantly finishes the execution, giving me the ">>>" prompt, as if it was done. And it is not working in the background, as I have tested a very simple program that sends me a mail, and it doesn't do it.

Something must have changed and maybe it uses another executable, but it is a silent crash.

Comment: You may need to enclose the program path in double quotes `"` since it appears it may contain embedded space characters.

Comment: Does that make a difference? Anyway, I never have spaces in my titles

Comment: However you do have spaces in your `programs` — and yes [it does matter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) when the first argument passed to `Popen` is single string.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a startup call you should ensure that `programCaller.py` is correctly called with the python you want so `"/path/to/Python/python" programCaller.py` I don't know how this works for Mac but on windows I would suggest you use https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/ to create an exe based on `programCaller.py`.

Also if you want to sort of debug this add a `time.sleep()` or a `print(p)` after the `p.communicate()` just to ensure the subprocess was created correctly. I am suggesting this because if you have different version of Python you might be missing some external libraries.

Something a bit more elaborate would be:

```
try:
    p = subprocess.Popen('/path/to/directory/' + program)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    print(stdout)
    print(stderr)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    p.kill()
    print("KeyboardInterrupt: killing process")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

if the subprocess doesn't need an input:

```
try:
    p = subprocess.Popen('/path/to/directory/' + program)
    output = p.stdout.readline()
    if output:
        sys.stdout.flush()
        print(output)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    p.kill()
    print("KeyboardInterrupt: killing process")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: I tried both with IDLE and from Terminal.
First one with IDLE: 
None
None,
First one from Terminal: 
None 
None
but then actually executed the code (send me an email),

2nd one in IDLE: 
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'readline',
2nd one from Terminal:
Same but executed the code

Comment: What do you mean @Alexandru to call it with the right Python? I have no problems calling the program from the Terminal. It just doesn't execute when I run it in IDLE (by pressing F5). It will silently crash. By playing around with subprocess.run and subprocess.call, I have occasionally received errors about /usr/bin/env python3 not being a directory... I will read the subprocess module well to figure this one out. In the meantime, from Terminal all works well